# Disable windows phone webbrowser control bounces

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

Windows phone webbrowser control bounces upon swipe events.But we want to disable this behavior to provide native app feel to end users.Here is the xaml code. can anybody help please?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <phone:WebBrowser Name="browser"
                      IsScriptEnabled="True"
                      ScriptNotify="browser_ScriptNotify"
                      Source="HTML/Default.html"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      />
</Grid>
```